# C++, why The element of array change by itself?

Tags: c++

Randomly order the number.
for example, the range is 4
This is my code Output.

```
Enter total number: 4
Number Guessing
3 1 4 2 Enter 4 digits(1-4) separated by a space
----------------------------------------
Round 1
Enter Guess:    3 1 4 2
                O O O O 
----------------------------------------
Congratulation! You win in 1 steps
RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 5s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Yes, it is ok. but if you change it more than 4. it will have the problem.

```
Enter total number: 5
Number Guessing
3 1 4 5 2 Enter 5 digits(1-5) separated by a space
----------------------------------------
Round 1
Enter Guess:    3 1 4 5 2
                O O O O X 
----------------------------------------
3 1 4 5 1330597711 Enter 5 digits(1-5) separated by a space
----------------------------------------
Round 2
Enter Guess:
```

The fifth element change from 2 to 1330597711! ??? I am a beginner.

THIS IS MY CODE!!!
Could you please help me to solve this problem? I want to know it

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    void shuffle(int* const arr, int size);
    int iSize,iCount=1;
    int* iCode = new int[iSize];
    char* iGuess= new char[iSize];
    cout<<"Enter total number: ";
    cin>>iSize;

    for(int i=0;i<iSize;i++){
        iCode[i]=i+1;
        iGuess[i]='O';
    }

    shuffle(iCode,iSize);
    cout<<"Number Guessing"<<endl;


    while(iSize>=4&&iSize<=20){
        for(int i=0;i<iSize;i++){
                cout<<iCode[i]<<" ";
            }   //print the code
        int n=1;
        for(int i=0;i<iSize;i++){
            iGuess[i]='O';
        }   //initialize char array;
        cout<<"Enter "<<iSize<<" digits(1-"<<iSize<<") separated by a space"<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Round "<<iCount<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter Guess:    ";
        for(int i=0;i<iSize;i++){
            int temp;
            cin>>temp;
            if(temp!=iCode[i]){
                iGuess[i]='X'; n=0;}
        }
        cout<<"                ";
        for(int i=0;i<iSize;i++){
        cout<<iGuess[i];cout<<" ";}
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<endl;
        if(n==1){
            cout<<"Congratulation! You win in "<<iCount<<" steps";
            break;
        }
        iCount+=1;
        }
        delete[] iCode,iGuess;
}
void shuffle(int* const arr, int size){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for(int i=0;i<(size-1);i++){
        int r=i+(rand()%(size-i));
        int temp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[r];
        arr[r]=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forget `new` and `delete`, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

This code is bugged, the statements are OK, but the order is wrong.

```
int iSize,iCount=1;
int* iCode = new int[iSize];
char* iGuess= new char[iSize];
cout<<"Enter total number: ";
cin>>iSize;
```

You are using the value of `iSize` before it has a value. Your code should be

```
int iSize,iCount=1;
cout<<"Enter total number: ";
cin>>iSize;
int* iCode = new int[iSize];
char* iGuess= new char[iSize];
```

In a program things happen in the order that you say. You should always make sure that your variables have a value before you use them.

Also this is wrong

```
delete[] iCode,iGuess;
```

should be

```
delete[] iCode;
delete[] iGuess;
```